# Proper way to parse and format a DateTime object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails I have DateTime object as:

```
2014-08-21 18:14:12 UTC
```

I want to display it as:

```
08-21-2014
```

I can hack this as follows:

```
"2014-08-21 18:14:12 UTC".to_s.sub(/(\d*)(-)(\d*-\d*)/, '\3\2\1').first(10)
```

But I prefer the proper Rails/ Ruby way and not having to convert the Date object to a string. Thanks!

Comment: See [`DateTime#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime).

Comment: http://strftime.net/ is also a good reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`DateTime#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime):

```
> DateTime.now.strftime '%m-%d-%Y'
=> "08-22-2014"
```

And please, please, *please* don’t use that format, unless you have no choice. Hyphens should only be used for the Y-m-d format. Use slashes or dots if possible. (Even better, use Y-m-d!)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `strftime` to get various formats of date & time.

```
 > DateTime.now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

 => "08-23-2014"
```

Read more about [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)